# numpy.core.multiarray failed to import BerTopic

Tags: numpy, importerror, numba, bert-language-model

execute this code
`from tqdm import tqdm from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer from konlpy.tag import Mecab from bertopic import BERTopic`

error list & method I tried below

1. Uninstall and Reinstall Numpy:
   I tried uninstalling and reinstalling numpy.

2.Downgrading numpy to 1.24.2:
When downgrading numpy to version 1.24.2, I encountered compatibility issues. The error messages are as follows:

```
`numba 0.57.1 requires numpy<1.25,>=1.21, but you have numpy 1.25.2 which is incompatible.
tensorflow 2.13.0 requires numpy<=1.24.3,>=1.22, but you have numpy 1.25.2 which is incompatible.`
```

3.Upgrading numpy to the latest version:
When I tried upgrading numpy to the latest version, I ran into an ImportError:

```
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import
NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt. To view examples of installing some common dependencies, click the "Open Examples" button below.
```

Please solve this problem...

Comment: !pip install --upgrade numba

!pip uninstall numpy
!pip install numpy==1.4.2
!pip install pyldavis